# WMS Request produces unexpected output

Tags: wms, getmap

I compiled this request to a WMS:

http://www.geoportal.tazv-luckau.de/arcgis/services/TAZV_Luckau/TWL_Luckau/mapserver/wmsserver?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&VERSION=1.3.0&LAYERS=TRINKWASSERLEITUNG&STYLES=&CRS=EPSG:25832&BBOX=(814982.1936043955,5748389.886124328,815982.1936043955,5749389.886124328)&FORMAT=image/tiff&WIDTH=1000&HEIGHT=1000

As you can see, the result is stretched along the y-axis. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Compare with this `http://www.geoportal.tazv-luckau.de/arcgis/services/TAZV_Luckau/TWL_Luckau/MapServer/WmsServer?
REQUEST=GetMap&
SERVICE=WMS&
VERSION=1.3.0&
WIDTH=1233&
HEIGHT=649&
LAYERS=Trinkwasserleitung&
TRANSPARENT=TRUE&
FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&
BBOX=784323.7233856706,5738936.794638,846507.1357143294,5771667.560738&
CRS=EPSG:25832&
STYLES=`

Comment: cool, how did you compile this?

Comment: Captured from OpenJUMP after doing Zoom to WMS layer. It has a tool "Display WMS URL" that is quite handy.

Comment: And OpenJUMP reads the extents as you can do also: `http://www.geoportal.tazv-luckau.de/arcgis/services/TAZV_Luckau/TWL_Luckau/MapServer/WmsServer?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a very good practice for editing wfs/wms etc. requests. [This](https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/wiki/Get-the-Raw-WMS-Request-Generated-by-QGIS) is the source.

- download and install the software "Fiddler" (Google will help you
  find its current download location)
- start Fiddler and leave it running
- in QGIS goto /Settings/Options/Network
- click on "Use proxy for web access"
- for Proxy Type select "HttpProxy"
- for Host enter: 127.0.0.1
- for Port enter: 8888
- presss "ok" button
- now Add a WMS/WFS/WCS layer in QGIS again, but watch the Fiddler window
- click on the request in Fiddler (such as GetCapabilities, GetMap, or GetCoverage)
- to see the full requested url in Fiddler, check the 'Inspector' tab, and then select 'Raw'
- then you can copy the raw url into a new browser window, load it, and examine the error and the url parameters

Comment: I will mark this as the answer, as it will then be shown on top.

Answer (score 1):

The first comment already hints at the solution, but since it's not *explicitly* mentioned, I'll add an answer:

The BBOX parameter should not have parentheses around the coordinates.

(As an aside: The extent in the question's URL does not seem to contain data)

Comment: that was the mistake indeed! thx